# Plank isn't showing up in Gnome Wayland session

Tags: 17.04, wayland, plank

After installing and setting up 17.04 Ubuntu Gnome, I tried Wayland session of Gnome, everything seemed to be little improved but [Plank dock](https://launchpad.net/plank) wasn't working at all. even after launching it from the app drawer, it doesn't show up

1. Is their a work around for this?
2. Can WaylandX help in this matter? if *yes* then how?
3. (as a last alternative) Are their some alternatives that closely resemble plank (has a mac like theme) and work on Wayland?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plank supports X11 environment only at the moment. For gnome shell you can use [Dash to Dock](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/) which is very similar.