# Any way to make plank work in Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: apt, 17.10, wayland, dock, plank

I installed `plank` from the stable ppa;

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:docky-core/stable
```

But it doesn't open, I tried to open it using the terminal, here is the output:

```
$plank
[WARN 19:35:57.039545] [Environment:161] XDG_SESSION_CLASS not set in this environment!
[CRITICAL 19:35:57.039626] [AbstractMain:257] Only X11 environments are supported
```

Also tried another answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908043/plank-isnt-showing-up-in-gnome-wayland-session) with no results.

I tried `Dash to Dock` and then realized it's the same as the default dock anyway.

Is there any way to use Plank on ubuntu 17.10, or maybe some other docks? (except `cairo-dock`, it uses a lot of memory, imo)

Comment: It says "only X11 environments is supported" Log in using Gnome X.org instead of Wayland.

Comment: @SorenA answer it please :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that "only X11 environments is supported". So probably you are logged in on Wayland. Log in with Gnome X.org instead and you wil be on X11.